# Pimcore linking objects to documents

Tags: pimcore

I'm trying to understand Pimcore.
Just for practice I've created a object called BlogItem.
I have a controller that is listing the BlogItems. Then I want to enable so when you click on a blog item header, only the blog item is displayed in the browser.

URL would be something like: http://www.domain.com/blog/view/1 (id).

How is this done with Pimcore?
Is there a guide for Pimcore that is describing how to do things like this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, but I will try to answer.

You get such an url if you 
a) create a new document (in this case you need to create the document blog and add a subdocument view into it. Problem is the "1", because this is an param. With documents it would look like /blog/view?id=1 or so.

b) you use static routes. You can create them via your admin interface. Here is a detailled how-to: http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Custom+Routes+(Static+Routes)

In both cases you can define a controller and a action name (which is in fact the method name in the controller, suffixed with Action).

HTH